# archiva extra file not visible

Tags: maven, archiva

I'm trying to also upload a deployment plan for certain web application projects.

This file has the extension '.dat'.

I can upload the file to archiva successfully using the deploy:deploy-file command. (checked by calling the url and it's there)

The problem i'm having is that i can't see the file in the downloads box on the screen when browsing to it, which makes it pretty pointless to upload it to archiva if noone can see that it's there.

Is this archiva only showing certain file types or is this a caching issue?

Where can I find more information about what is being shown in that box?[image: downloads box]

archiva version: 
   Apache Archiva 1.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is go to the "Repository Scanning" tab, and ensure that `**/*.dat` files are included in the list of artifacts to be detected. Afterwards, you will need to go t the "Repositories" tab and scan the repository again to have it appear.

Comment: I've added the file type to the 'artifacts' part from 'Repository Scanning - File Types' from 'Administration - Repository Scanning'. I also Went to 'Administration - Repositories', 'Managed Repositories' and clicked the 'Scan Repository Now' button for the appropriate repository. It didn't work, but what i noticed is that the 'Last Scanned' time didn't get updated when clicking it.

Comment: Finaly managed to get it to show. It was archiva that didn't respond the way it should anymore. After restarting archiva it now shows the file. Thx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm that's not part of the visible files.
BTW that should work with last 1.4*